# MVC3 MapRoute problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TestRoute4", // Route name
    "Report {ref_id} Test Board", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "stats", action = "index" } // Parameter defaults
);

public ActionResult index(string ref_id)
{
}
```

This works good but I would now like my controller to know that it's been called from a route that matched Report 25 Test Board. Is there a way in MapRoute that I can also pass other things to the controller? I don't even mind hardcoding. I just just want to pass the words Report and Test Board.

Hope you can help,

Mandy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataTokens`:

```
Route route = routes.MapRoute(
    "TestRoute4", // Route name
    "Report {ref_id} Test Board", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "stats", action = "index" } // Parameter defaults
);

route.DataTokens["YourKey"] = "your value";
```

On your controller you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

   // check if matched route is TestRoute4 (optional)
   if (this.RouteData.Route == RouteTable.Routes["TestRoute4"]) {
      // do something

      var val = this.RouteData.DataTokens["YourKey"];
   }

}
```